# How to change sentence with 'ensure that...' to passive form

Tags: passive-voice

Ensure that there is no short circuit.
How to change this kind of sentences to passive form?

Comment: It's an imperative. To change it to passive, the subject *you* must necessarily become the object and the object *that there is no short circuit* the subject. But that makes the imperative no longer directed to you rather to the class *that there be no short circuit* (in Spanish we'd term it an exhortative statement, but not imperative, not sure on standard English terminology). But, theoretically, it'd be *Be it ensured by you that there is no short circuit* which I highly, highly, don't would actually be naturally and casually uttered by any native speaker of Modern English.

Comment: Err... Sorry, typed too quickly on phone. *doubt* not *don't*, and subjects become agents in a complement introduced with *by* (I wish SE would allow edits more than 5min out)

Comment: That there is no short circuit should be ensured (by you). It is an alternative formation instead of 'let' construction frequently used in imperative voice changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence is an imperative sentence as commented above. You use the verb "let" when you change an imperative to a passive voice (form).

> Learn this poem by heart. 
>   = Let this poem be learned by heart (by you).
>
> Do it at once. 
>   = Let it be done at once (by you).

The same rule applies to your sentence.

> Ensure that there is no short circuit. = Let ***it*** be ensured
>   ***that*** there is no short circuit (by you).

You have to use "dummy ***it***" or a "[placeholder](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/placeholder)" as the object ((that there is no short circuit)) of the imperative is too long .

"Placeholder" is:

> [Linguistics] An element of a sentence that is required by syntactic
>   constraints but ***carries little or no semantic information***.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]